# How to display a form after clicking on a button using Javascript ? Why is this code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The form is hidden using CSS. But, I want to display it after clicking on Apply button. I also tried `document.getElementById("applicationform").style.visibility:"visible";` but it is also not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("applicationform").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#applicationform {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Apply</button>
<div id="applicationform">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="Submit" value="SUBMIT">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I created the stack snippet and it is working as expected

Comment: It is working in the snippet.

Comment: Perhaps you could recreate a version in context?

Comment: Try to use the toggle function : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: Ya, it is working here . Idk why it was not working on notepad++. But thanks.